# Does DB2 honour maximum length of data type?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

DB2 Details:

- product name : DB2/LINUXX8664
- version : 10.5.0.5

As per DB2 docs, Maximum length of `varchar` is  **32704 bytes**

I tried:

```
create table t_varchar (c1 varchar(32673));
```

Got the error:

> Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-604, SQLSTATE=42611, SQLERRMC=varchar(32673), DRIVER=4.14.111
>   SQLState:  42611
>   ErrorCode: -604

It allowed me to create varchar with max length 32672.

Is this desired behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

Simlilarly, for CHAR I am not able to create table with `char(255)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You left out details on your default tablespace and page size, so I am assuming you are going with the defaults. The maximum row sizes are documented as part of [CREATE TABLE](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000927.html). The varchar size you are using is only possible with 32k pages which is not the default page size. So I would expect that error message.

There are also details in terms of value compression, NULL values, etc. that contribute to column size and row size.